# When I shutdown the Zope server it shows an AttributeError

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x

I am using Plone 4.3.3 for creating my Plone site but when I shut-down the server it shows the following error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/bin/interpreter", line 298, in <module>
    exec(compile(__file__f.read(), __file__, "exec"))
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 26, in run
    starter.run()
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 108, in run
    self.shutdown()
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 113, in shutdown
    db.close()
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/DB.py", line 624, in close
user@user-Vostro-3300:~/Plone/zinstance$     @self._connectionMap
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/DB.py", line 506, in _connectionMap
    self.pool.map(f)
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/DB.py", line 206, in map
    self.all.map(f)
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transaction-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/transaction/weakset.py", line 58, in map
    f(elt)
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/DB.py", line 628, in _
    c._release_resources()
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 1075, in _release_resources
    c._storage.release()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'release'
```

Comment: What is in your buildout.cfg, what operating system are you using, and was this working before correctly, and if so what changed recently?

Comment: This is a relstorage thing, not caused by it, but only seen by its users, and is due to this commit in Zope2.  https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/commit/5032027470091957a6c0028da04c0fc0a1ed646b  Should be cosmetic, though annoying. Context: https://mail.zope.org/pipermail/zodb-dev/2013-August/015119.html

Comment: @sdupton post that as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with Zope2 shutdown that tries to close a database connection (and in turn, a storage).  However, this late-running sequence has some cosmetic side-effect for users of RelStorage.  This is annoying, but not fundamentally a problem that should cause any data integrity issues.

Users of FileStorage or ZEO should not see this.

References:
https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/commit/5032027470091957a6c0028da04c0fc0a1ed646b

https://mail.zope.org/pipermail/zodb-dev/2013-August/015119.html

Comment: Thankyou for clear my doubt and if you got any solution  ¨to stop ¨  this trace then please mention me there