# AttributeError when restarting

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

Our production system works as a cluster of Zope workers that have a ZEO server as a backend, pretty usual stuff.

As we have quite a lot of data our instances consume too much memory and we have a watchdog that restarts them whenever they go above a limit. The restarting code is basically:

```
bin/supervisorctl reload
```

Whenever that happens we get quite a lot of emails from our workers with stacktraces like (and that's the full stacktrace):

```
Couldn't load state for 0x052aec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/service/.buildout/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 860, in setstate
    self._setstate(obj)
  File "/home/service/.buildout/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 901, in _setstate
    p, serial = self._storage.load(obj._p_oid, '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'
```

I thought it was normal until I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326932) which was pointing that that could only happen to RelStorage users, and we are not using RelStorage...

Any idea on if that indicates something or we can (as we already do, although it bothers me) just automatically mark those messages from our workers as read on our mail client?

Is there any nicer/softer way to tell a Zope worker to restart? Some sort of a *"finish the request you are dealing with and then restart"*

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in a test-env and if so, does then removing supervisor and restarting server and clients manually (./bin/zeoserver restart; ./bin/client1 restart; ...) let the error dissapear?

Comment: @IdaEbkes yes I can, having ``bin/zeo fg`` and ``bin/instance fg`` and then while doing a request ``Ctrl+C``'ing bin/instance shows that traceback as well

Comment: That's good, in terms of, it excludes, it could have been a supervisor's bug :-) If I got you right, the error is reproducable in a fresh instance? That might be worth a bug-report, especially as it's not only concerning rel-storage.

Comment: This quest is now referenced on: https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/commit/5032027470091957a6c0028da04c0fc0a1ed646b